# Select single fields more than one time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my select query in `contact_group` table I am inserting more than one record for same `contact_id`

now my problem is when i am fetching name of group from group table for same `contact_id` it gives me more than one row in result but i want to fetch all group name with single row result

```
$query  = "SELECT *,group_name FROM contact";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN contact_group ON contact_group.contact_id = contact.contact_id";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN `group` ON `group`.`group_id` = contact_group.group_id";
$query .= " GROUP BY contact_group.contact_id";
```

Comment: Really need to have some sample data and sample input/output here.  It's hard to help when we have no idea what the query is picking from, what it IS doing with that data, and what you expect it to do with that data.

Comment: if me define my table structure than it's helpful to you @Malkierian

Comment: You shouldn't use select * in your query as it is returning all unique columnvalues from the joined tables as well.

Comment: than what is way? @avk

Comment: Replace * with the actual columns from the tables you need before grouping. What group by does is group where values are the same. Since primary keys are unique your current query will never group.